# Hide Qualtrics Item Upon Previous Response - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, qualtrics

I want to add a listener on one of the questions so that when a participant choices a specific multiple choice response it hides or reveals the next question. But I want the two questions in the same block.

For example;

(1) Which of the following do you want? A, B, C, D

(2) (Display only if not D) For how long?

So, I suppose my main questions are; which question do I put the Javascript in and how do I set up the listener?

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is built-in to Qualtrics, so you don't need JavaScript.  Add display logic to the second question and check "In Page".